# Engine locked up I think need serious help please

Tags: engine

Need help, first car. Was gonna change oil when made to Walmart town over but car messed up a mile outside of town. Oil was completely empty and car i guess overheated and fluids came out from that. Instantly pulled over And killed car so think motor is locked can I fix any way other than replacing? It's a 2005 Chevy impala

Answer (score 1):

First Check the water level when engine has cooled down top-up if needed, check your oil level then top up a little at a time 1/2 pint amounts until the level is half way between the min & max on your dip stick.All assuming the engine turns over and isnt siezed! you should be able to start the car if your battery is ok and drive home,check the levels again when it cools down...